# how to add two dataframes with different column names vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python using pandas, I have two dataframes df1 and df2 as shown in figure below. Is there any way to add the two dataframes vertically to obtain a 3rd dataframe "df3" to look like as shown in the figure below.

Thanks in advance
[image: dataframes DF1, DF2 and DF3]

Comment: i have already tried pd.concat and df1.append(df2). Both of them can merge the dataframes but not in the intended way. There is no way I achieved 2 rows of heading names in a single datframe and that is the whole problem for me

Comment: post you code and data table in valid for to recreate problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Concatenate pandas** check out this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)
if you have basic knowledge in Pandas the application should be no problem.